# SHA 1 Interemediate Signer for a SHA2 Personal Certificate

Tags: tls, sha2

I came across a certificate that has a signer that is SHA1 but it is a SHA2 certificate.  Is this actually allowed or is did the CA screw up ?  Would it work with a TLS 1.2 negotiation?

Comment: Is the SHA1 the root or an intermediate?  Note that the SHA1 problem does not impact trusted root certs because, by definition, they're trusted; their authority derives from you having them and not from being checked against their signature.

Comment: It is the root certificate that has it.  So that has answered my question.  Thanks!!!